# How to change stylesheet ordering of base and child theme?

Tags: 7, commerce, theming

I have downloaded [Drupal Commerce](https://drupal.org/project/commerce) and started playing around with it. I have a new theme created using [Commerce Kickstart](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart) as base. My theme is in `sites/all/themes`. Any styles that I put in the stylesheets of my new theme are being overridden by the base drupal commerce stylesheet.

How can I make sure my styles get applied on top of the default?

Comment: The sub-theme CSS files will usually be loaded after those of the base theme (definitely in the case of Commerce Kickstart, I've just checked one of my own installations). Are you sure it's not your CSS selectors that are the problem? If not, could you give examples of the selectors you're using, and of the file names that are coming out in the wrong order?

Comment: I am sure some thing is wrong with your Css file , because I just checked with my theme on Commerce and it loaded all Css as its should be!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you look into the  section of your code, can you find the css file? If not, it can be that the css is aggregated (in this case you'll find a random alphabetic css file), then clear your cache. If there is no aggregation, and you can't find your file, it is most probably set wrong in your theme.info file.

If the file is there, but not working, check in your browser (via fe element inspect) if and why the selectors are overridden...